# How to find the intersection of the graphs of $y= x^2$ and $y = 6 - |x|$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume, absolute-value

I was trying to solve this question in preparation for the Math subject GRE exam:

> The region bounded by the graphs of $y=x^{2}$ and $y=6-|x|$ is revolved around the $y$ -axis. What is the volume of the generated solid?
> (A) $\frac{32}{3} \pi$ 
> (B) $9 \pi$ 
> (C) $8 \pi$
> (D) $\frac{20}{3} \pi$ 
> (E) $\frac{16}{3} \pi$

So first I was trying to find the intersection of the graphs of $y= x^2$ and $y = 6 - |x|.$   I did that by equating $ x^2 = 6 - |x|.$ Then I ended up having 2 equations which are $ x^2 - 6 + x = 0 $ and $ x^2 - 6 - x = 0 $, and then I got four values of $x$, which are $\pm 3, \pm 2.$ But I found in the answer for the question that they consider only the two values $\pm 2.$

Could anyone show me what is wrong in my solution or in the book solution (the book just gave me the values $\pm 2$ without explaining how and why), please?

Comment: Did you try plotting $y=x^2$ and $y=6-|x|$?

Comment: Visually, looking at the graph shows that there would indeed only ever be 2 solutions. $\pm3$ are [extraneous solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20an%20extraneous%20solution,valid%20solution%20to%20the%20problem.).

Comment: @fleablood I do not understand your comment. Could you clarify, please?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes I did. but I did not find any hindering for the negative values.

Comment: Not $6 - |x| \le 6$ so $y=x^2 > 6$ is impossible.

Comment: May I know the form number, please? I did not find this problem in GR0568, GR1768, GR8767, GR9367, nor GR9368. Possibly from other source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions should be ($x^2-6+x=0$ and $x\ge0$) or ($x^2-6-x=0$ and $x\le0)$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Indeed, the takeaway is that $x\geq0$ and $x\leq0$ must be specified when splitting $|x|$ into two equations.

Comment: Sure thanks for clarification :) Tanner

Answer (score 0):

No need to define cases: as $|x|^2=x^2$, you only need to find the nonnegative roots of the equation
$$ t^2+t-6=0.$$
(Vieta's relations show it has a positive and a negative root) and deduve the values of $x$.